# Using validate_change function in elixir throws error

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

So I want to validate an email input field in elixir(phoenix framework)

I get this error

```
** (BadArityError) &String.downcase/1 with arity 1 called with 2 arguments (:email, "HARRY@POTTER.com")
    (ecto) lib/ecto/changeset.ex:1573: Ecto.Changeset.validate_change/3
```

Here is my code

```
    |> validate_change(:email, &String.downcase(&1))


    |> validate_length(:password, min: 6, max: 100)
    |> validate_confirmation(:password)
    |> unique_constraint(:email)
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Ecto.Changeset.validate_change/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html?#validate_change/3) requires a function of arity 2 as the validator, it receives both *field name* and *field value*.

Another issue would be `String.downcase/1` can hardly be a validator since it hardly validates anything and it does not return

```
 [{atom(), String.t()} | {atom(), {String.t(), Keyword.t()}}]
```

type as it is required by the contract.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to check email in downcase ?

```
validate_change(:email, fn :email, email ->
  case email == String.downcase(email) do
    true -> []
    false -> [email: "Please enter downcase email]"
  end
end)
```

Or convert email to downcase ?

```
defp downcase_email(changeset) do
  case changeset do
    %Ecto.Changeset{valid?: true, changes: %{email: email}} ->
      put_change(changeset, :email, String.downcase(email))

    _ ->
      changeset
  end
end
```